# Guice: How to dynamically update definitions in a module w/out losing preexisting singletons

Tags: java, guice

I would like to (re)create another Injector using the definitions already a part of another Injector with the following:

- add, remove, replace existing definitions
- singletons belonging to existing definitions in the "source" injector are carried over to the "new" injector.

Answer (score 2):

The [Guice SPI](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ExtendingGuice) may help, albeit even partially. Guice 3.0 allows you to query the `Injector` for the current bindings.

The injector maintains immutable state for each binding so your success with this may or may not be the best.

Comment: Not really an answer, your just guessing - the only possible answer is obviously the SPI. Take a look at how singletoness is maintained - basically guice create a provider which wraps the real source, the wrapped holds the singleton and only calls the real source if its empty. Answer how to get around that and we have an answer.

Comment: @mP: You're completely missing the fundamentals that Guice is based on. You _don't_ want people fiddling with bindings as it can result is strange and unreproducible errors. To try achieve what you want, you'll need to use the SPI and recreate all the bindings that the current injector is maintaining, applying the mutations along the way. Although, looking at you want to do, I would caution against it as the Guice developers have gone to a lot of effort to prevent such on the fly modifications, and with good reason.